# How to import the class GlassStream into my project?

Tags: android, google-glass

I am trying to get a video stream running from Google Glass. I already tried spydroid, but for some reason it is not giving any video output.

Now I am trying to import `GlassStream` into eclipse, but all of the package declarations and imports are broken(i did follow the given instructions):
The declared package `net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.video` does not match the expected package `src.net.majorkernelpanic.streaming.video`

If I fix all of those manually, then I get that R class is not found.

It is the first time I am dealing with Google Glass, and I don't know what the issue here is, the spydroid v10 project imported flawlessly.

Link: https://github.com/andermaco/GlassStream

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I had to pull out all of the sub-folders, set the project source folders, and put everything where it belongs.